# CMake: "add_library IMPORTED" check if the lib exists

Tags: android-ndk, cmake

I am importing a static lib in CMAKE using [add_library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/add_library.html).
The lib imports fine.But I also want to verify that.So I do this:

```
add_library(MYLIB STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(MYLIB PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION path/to/mylib.a)
#if(NOT  MYLIB)
  #  message(FATAL_ERROR "MYLIB library not found")
#endif()
```

It always returns false, even when the path is correct and the lib is imported ok.How can I check that the lib is imported?

Using Cmake 3.4.1

Comment: Please add Android NDK tags to your question. Many people avoid answering questions for platforms they have no clue about and in this case, you are not able to even accept my correct standard CMake answer.

Answer (score 3):

Command `add_library()` creates a **target**, not a *variable*.

Target existence can be checked with *TARGET* keyword:

```
add_library(MYLIB STATIC IMPORTED)
#...

if(NOT TARGET MYLIB)
   # Target is not exist
endif()
```

Note, that existence of the library *target* **doesn't mean** existence of the library *file*. Existence of the file should use *EXISTS* keyword:

```
if(EXISTS <path>)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are failing/stopping processing anyway, then you could check it is imported by trying to use the library!

If you actually want to check before you import, then something like this may be appropriate:

```
find_library(MYLIB
  NAMES mylib
  PATHS
    path/to/mylib.a
  DOC "Find library mylib"
  NO_DEFAULT_PATH)

if(NOT MYLIB)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "MYLIB library not found")
endif()
```

You can remove `NO_DEFAULT_PATH` if you don't mind CMake looking in all the many default locations first before searching your stated PATHS.

Comment: I forgot to mention - I don't use  'find library ' on purpose. Android NDK makes it a real pain to locate non NDK libs with that method because they set default search path to some internal NDK dir. That's the reason I switched to add_library ... Also I want to spit a clear error message that the lib can't be found. As you probably know, sometimes, tools end users are not so smart as we may think to figure out the source of a problem   ;)

Comment: @Michael Ivanov Then the only other alternative I can suggest is using `IF(EXISTS path/to/mylib.a)`